# Creating a Price tracker system

Tags: large-data

I was recently asked the following question in an interview.

"How would you design a system to keep track of a million items at xyz.com ?
The xyz.com could update the prices maybe 2-3 times a day or once per month, so no guarentee on frequency.
Your system should show accurate prices for >95% of items at any given point of time and aim for 99%.
Also scale for 1billion items etc..
"

I asnwered along the lines of creating a distributed system app that would categorize items by priority (based on historical price fluctuations and 80/20 % rule etc) and do API calls more frequently for these.

But I was not allowed to use API calls.

I suggested scraping html content. (But the website can block my ip for such high load)

I basically want to know the resources that would help me anwering these type of questions. Prefer full length courses (Distributed systems ?) or books rather than quick-fix blogs.

Comment: I think your question is too broad for Stackoverflow. Maybe you are lucky and you still receive good answers. If not, you could try quora.com.

Comment: Ask xyz.com to send you an event each time a price changes. However this may cause higher volume than it necessary. A daily feed of price information would probably be fine, to be processed overnight. However, this is not scalable to 1BN.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this?